# How to delay mouseout event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

The below code allows me to show vertical menu on hover but it fades away immediately once mouseout event. I am not a coder, what I did was just played with code available around everywhere, but please.

```
if($(columnElement).length 
        && $(window).width() >= maxWindowSize) {          
    showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 1);
}

$(".float-vertical-button").hover(function(){   
   var numberToUse = $(menuElement).hasClass('active') ? 0 : 1;
   showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, numberToUse);
});
```

Comment: You have to play with setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.hover()` is actually 2 events chained together.  (`mouseenter` and `mouseleave`).
You should specify them separately. E.g:

```
$( ".float-vertical-button" ).hover(

  //Mouse enter handler
  function() {
    showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 1);
  }, 

  //Mouse leave handler
  function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 0);
    }, 500);
  }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: I have a question here; when mouse is moved out from the displayed menu, the menu still stays there. I am trying to achieve similar function as in amazon menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap your logic in a setTimeout() function.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    $c('hide!');
    hideUnderConstruction();
  }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(columnElement).length && $(window).width()>=maxWindowSize) 
    showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 1);
$(".float-vertical-button").hover(function(){   
    if($(menuElement).hasClass('active')) setTimeout(showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 0), 1000);
    else showOrHideSliderBarMenu(columnElement, menuElement, 1);
});
```

Where 1000 is the time in milliseconds you wish to delay

Comment: This does not work, though it does not give any error.

Comment: there is no effect on behaviour, not even a second delay, i tried increasing 1000 to 9000 and other ranges.